# Can't login after upgrade

Tags: release-freya, greeter, updates

The default Software Updater was not working correctly. It was giving the message "An upgrade from 'freya' to 'trusty' is not supported with this tool."

So I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And rebooted.

After the reboot I am unable to login. I type my password, the screen goes black as if it was going to login, and I'm back at the same screen.

I can tell the password is correct because when I type the wrong password, it gives that shaking animation. I even tried using the on-screen keyboard to type my password, so I know it's not a problem with my keyboard configuration or anything like this.

Also, I am not able to login with the guest account.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What did you upgrade _from_, to? Did you do the unsupported action of upgrading from an elementary release to a Ubuntu release?

Comment: I installed Freya when it was on beta, but it upgraded normally to the final version. There has been some time since the last upgrade I did, so I suppose it was upgrading to elementary 0.3.1.

Comment: I didn't change anything, so I don't see how it would try to upgrade from elementary to Ubuntu.

Comment: Well from "Freya" to "Trusty" is from elementary to Ubuntu, though technically the same version, which I don't quite understand (as in, why it would try to do this).

Comment: @RolandiXor For future reference, this happens because sources point to trusty but Freya is labelled as freya. The system assumes it's an upgrade.

Comment: For me worked to start with elementary recovery mode and clean some space through this utility.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have a crystal ball, but I suppose to look for .Xauthority in your home folder, there might be a permission problem:

1. Press CTRL+ALT+F1 (but if you on mackbook do CTRL+FN+F1) to get to a prompt, and login.
2. Check the permissions and owner of your home directory: `ls -l ~/.Xauthority`
3. Change the owner of the file, if it is not yours, by `chown username:username .Xauthority`.

Comment: I tried it. It seems like I already am the owner. Still, I did "chow guilherme:guilherme .Xauthority", but I still can't login.

Comment: Thank you, this saved me after I broke things screwing around!

Comment: This worked for me. Root was the owner and I changed it to my user.

Answer (score 3):

You could try reinstalling the desktop environment going into the TTY (`CRTL+ALT+F1`) and running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop
```

After that, reboot using the command

```
sudo reboot
```

If everything went right, you should be able to login again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I did this:

1. Press CTRL+ALT+F1 to get to a prompt, and login.
2. sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
3. sudo reboot

If this does not work, try to create another user account from the prompt.

```
sudo useradd new-admin-username -s /bin/bash -g sudo -m
```

> -s sets the user login shell
> -m makes home directory for the new user
> -g give the new user admin privileges

```
sudo passwd new-admin-username
```

also on elementary Os if you have a bootable usb you can go to recovery boot and enter to root and next add an user and you can login without problems..

Answer (score 1):

- Login to tty1 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
- Enter username and password
- Run the command `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. First, it gave me the message: "gdm: unrecognized service". It seems like lightdm is used in newer versions of Ubuntu instead of gdm. So I tried "sudo service lightdm restart". It restarted, but still, I can't login.

Comment: I even installed kdm, just to see if it wasn't a problem with lightdm, but I still wasn't able to login.

Comment: this worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was:

- reboot and start with a old kernel version
- upgrade:

  sudo apt- get update && sudo apt- get upgrade
- reboot normally.

For now it works, but Updates show me that message.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers didn't fix my problem.
I fixed it by installing the latest [NVidia drivers](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, in my case all the trouble was caused because **my hard drive was full**(i was using a Virtual Machine). I delete some unnecessary files (ALT + CTRL + F1 for using console)  and i could login again. After that i just upgrade the VM disk and now is work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First Ctrl + Alt + F4 ( In black screen )

Later will ask login and password , do the normal login and then the following commands:

sudo apt- get update && sudo apt- get upgrade

sudo apt- get install xserver- xorg

sudo reboot

https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Novo-no-Linux/Tela-preta-ao-iniciar-ubuntu-14?pagina=02

Answer (score 0):

I tried pretty much every solution posted here. I am running Elementary 0.4.1 Loki, and the day-before-yesterday i ran some updates trough the AppCenter, and these updates requred a reboot for some reason. After that reboot i couldn't log in. What finally solved the problem for me, after trying everything else posted here i did this - I ran the ecrypt-mount-private command and i was asked for a login passphrase. I tried entering my password but it didn't work - i must confess i'm pretty much a total noob when it comes to Linux distros - so then I got the idea of entering my old (original) passower (the one i had set whe installing Elementary). That decrypted my home directory. The I exited the CLI by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7 and got back to the GUI, and entered my current account password and I managed to log in. Hope this helps. At the moment I am installing 5.0 Juno :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm a new user for Elementary OS. About the error that make you can't login into it. I had some advice maybe can be useful. The first I Installed this,

1. I activate automatically login when I'm installing the Elementary OS.
2. The second thing that I did,I had removed the apps that I didn't need,Idk it has a relationship with the data login that can cause and error or not. The only app that I removed is calculator and I don't anything expect that. Well beacuse I was too afraid about the error that hard to find out about it
3. I test with sudo apt-get update,even I try sudo apt-get upgrade,I do it twice
4. Even I install wifi driver that do update and upgrade
5. I have seen the error like firmware ,but now i didn't see it anymore,idk why
6. Oh right,don't remove the feedback

And now even after I suspend or in lock mode,I can unlock it. I felt depressed aboout this,I hope my advice can help you. I curious about why the developer doesn't tell us how to fix it. Or why he didn't have an old version before 5.1.

Github : Nura21

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by graphics driver update.
In my case, **nvidia-340**(*put your graphics driver name here*) driver patch update case this problem.

Simple solution that I follow is,

First of all, login in your tty shell by `Ctl+Alt+F1`
And run following commands,

1. remove graphics driver

   `sudo apt remove nvidia-340`
2. reinstall elementary-desktop

   `sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop`
3. reboot the system

   `sudo reboot`