# I can't login , return to login screen (it isn't Xauthority)

Tags: greeter

I spend all day trying to fix the problem but it was impossible.
I updated my OS from update manager. I ran a game on steam and the pc has got freeze and then, I rebooted whit button.

When I try to login in login screen, appear one second the desktop, then back to login screen.

I reinstalled the headers, I checked the Xauthority and several other things but anything worked.

I need help!!

EDIT: my OS is Elementary OS Freya.
I already tried:

- [Check out Xauthority](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/cant-login-after-upgrade)
- [Remove Steam and Steam Games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227502/where-are-steam-games-installed)
- [All this](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2eade1/stuck_at_login_screen/)
- [sudo apt-get install --install-recommends...](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2241210)
- [remove unity-greeter but It is not installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203391/elementary-os-accidentally-installed-ubuntu-login-screen)

EDIT 2:

- [removed two files](https://answers.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+question/231335)

EDIT 3:

- sudo apt-get install --reinstall plank
- sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-tweaks
- Installed last graphics drivers from [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.0)

EDIT 4:

- [VIDEO EXPLAINING ISSUE](https://vid.me/HTUx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an user and I could join in.
Removed elementary-tweaks and numix-icon then I could join again with my user...

I installed again elementary tweaks and it works.

I hope this works for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reinstalling Pantheon Desktop?

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop
```

Or reinstalling pantheon-greeter (you have tried to reinstall lightdm, but it's called pantheon-greeter)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pantheon-greeter
```

Comment: I have tried right now but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with the same issue. I unfortunately ran earlier that that the

```
sudo chmod 777 -R .
```

command in my root directory, which changed all the permission on my computer, included my account. My account permission also change, therefore I was not allowed to log in into my account.
Solution:
When I ran the command again it solved the problem,I could log in into my account, but it's highly recommended to reinstall the compute for security reasons.