# Loki - Black screen for 10-15 minutes after login

Tags: greeter, release-loki, nvidia

I've installed Loki on a new machine running dual monitors. I have an Nvidia NVS310 card, I'm using 340.96 Nvidia proprietary drivers. When I login in the morning after locking the machine the night before I login successfully but then my screen is black, I get a mouse cursor but I can't move the mouse cursor. If I leave it alone, 10-15 minutes later both screens come up normally and the machine functions fine the rest of the day.

I can SSH into the machine from another machine. I can't VNC in from another machine eventhough the servce is running. The CTRL + ALT +Fx keys don't do anything. I've gone through the DMESG file and the /var/log/Xorg.0.log and nothing seems out of place. (I can attach those if anything thinks that would help.)

The only thing I can think to try next is changing the Nvidia driver. Alternatively I'm going looking for other log files pertaining to Nvidia or graphics in general.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:** After I switched through several nvidia drivers now I cannot log in. I'm in the same situation I was in before ([I get logged out as soon as I log in](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7279/i-get-logged-out-as-soon-as-i-log-in)) but apparently *sudo nvidia-uninstall* doesn't do anything now.

Answer (score 2):

After several attempts of completely wiping the suite of pre-installed Nvidia drivers and attempting to install new ones off the website I cut my losses and reinstalled. After I reinstalled **I did not attempt to update to any Nvidia drivers this install.** I'm just using the default nouveau drivers and haven't had any graphical issues.