# can't log back in to Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki 64bit

Tags: release-loki, system-installation, pantheon-files, greeter

I am unable to login back to my os. and yes, I am using the correct password. whenever I login it shows black screen like it is logging me in and then it shows the password prompt again.
after spending considerable time looking though this website and searching for an answer to this question, I did most of the things mentioned as a possible solution to this question but nothing worked.
also, I was able to create a new admin account which is working fine and I am able to login to this but I am still unable to login to my main account.

from what I remember, the only thing that I updated from the app center was Microcode update, which was an update from intel.
I was thinking to uninstall that but I am worried that it might break the system?
as I don't know how to roll back to the last version.

what all things I have done so far :-

1. reinstalled elementary-desktop
2. reinstalled pantheon-greeter
3. checked the permissions and ownership of .Xauthority, The ownership is correct.
4. restarted lightdm service
5. after upgrading apt-get, i installed xserver-xorg.

Edit1 :
on this topic below, the person was able to resolve the issue after reinstalling elementary-tweaks and numix-icon.
but I don't have either of them installed on my os. :((

[I can't login , return to login screen (it isn't Xauthority)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2568/i-cant-login-return-to-login-screen-it-isnt-xauthority)

Comment: since you other (the new admin acct) account is working fine ... does not appear to the the microcode update ... it may be that something got corrupted in you hidden config file in your home directory(acct not working)  ... not sure if this will work ... not trying this since I need to go to work now ...

Comment: you can try first by creating a test acct to try this on to make sure that it doesn't make things worse ... try first deleting the hidden files directly under your home ... then try the hidden directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after spending nearly 4 days trying to figure out this issue and trying to resolve it. I figured it out.
It seems the issue was coming from my dconf user file.
it is the file that contains configuration data for dconf.
I renamed it and now it is all working fine.

Thank u all for whatever help u provided, really appreciate it. thanks.