# Cant Login after update to the last version of greeter

Tags: greeter

I after a system update when i restarted my computer cant login in my main account. After i type the password screen goes black and throw me again at login screen. I cant  login with as guest because its the same error
how can i enter in my account ?

[image]

Comment: Im in the last version of hera 5.1

Comment: can you boot with old kernel? this link maybe useful for your: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/cant-login-after-upgrade
 try login to terminal and reinstall desktop packages.

Comment: The solution was, that my space left in my disk was full , I need to give some gigabytes to my "/" partition from gparted (boot with a ubuntu live usb) and it login again.