# unable to login starting session failed returned error code 1

Tags: release-hera, greeter, dual-boot

I dual booted my laptop to have windows 10 and elementaryos 5.1 hera. I was updating some apps from appcenter and cancelled 2 updates (i assume this is what caused the problem). I now cant login no matter what I do and i've checked all the posts here about it and it doesn't fix anything. I have a lot of files on it so I would like to keep them is there any solution to this problem? I really like this OS and i would try anything to get it working again.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like greeter is having trouble but that means your computer is booting properly.
Can you login using a different TTY?
Press *Ctrl+Alt+F1* or possibly *Ctrl+FN+F1* on a Macbook to access a different TTY.
You can finish your update from the command-line with `sudo apt upgrade`.
To reboot after finishing the updates you can run `systemctl reboot`.

If you still have issues it appears that many people have solved this by changing the ownership of the `~/.Xauthority` file to the appropriate user.
You might have already tried this but I'll include in just in case.
You can reference the solution [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2462/20782) and I've included it below.

1. Login to your user account through a different TTY by pressing *Ctrl+Alt+F1* or possibly *Ctrl+FN+F1* on a Macbook.
2. Set the permissions on the `~/.Xauthority` file so that you own the file.

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.Xauthority
```

3. Reboot.

```
systemctl reboot
```